# Convert text field to Date/time field ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi guys can i ask if it's possible to convert a text field to a date/time field?

for example i have a field called Month and the field is a short text data type.

Here is an example:

Month
Sep 2016
Nov 2016
Dec 2016

is it possible that i could convert this one to a date time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateValue("1 " & Month)
```

I'm assuming you want to put the first of the month in the date.

Output should be

```
9/1/2016
11/1/2016
12/1/2016
```

in your case

Comment: i mean how do i convert nov 2016, dec 2016 etc. to a date since i have this as text data type. not date/time data type.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know the output you're getting.

Comment: Btw can i ask i get an error if i try to update it UPDATE DateValue("1 " & Month) FROM futures

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider to vote / accept the answer if it's a correct one to you question.

Comment: The correct syntax of update query should be: `UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = [Value] WHERE [CONDITION]`. Refer to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-run-an-update-query-9dddc97c-f17d-43f4-a729-35e5ee1e0514#__toc336583665

Answer (score 0):

SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 2015 12', 0)  or
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 2015', 0) or
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 2015')

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy that it can't be simpler:

```
FirstOfMonth: CDate([Month])
```

The values will be *primo* of [Month].